# Typescript Array push only show latest item

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list get from my API, like as :

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "trainingClassId": 1,
      "examCode": "my exam 1",
      "address": {
        "addressId": 1,
        "addressValue": "abc 1213"
      },
      "description": "only test",
      "classId": null,
      "startDate": 1511110800000,
      "endDate": 1513702800000,
     "examDate": 1511542800000

    },
    {
      "trainingClassId": 2,
      "examCode": "my exam 2",
      "address": {
        "addressId": 1,
        "addressValue": "abc 1213"
      },
      "description": "only test",
      "classId": null,
      "startDate": 1511110800000,
      "endDate": 1513702800000,
     "examDate": 1511542800000
    }
  ],
  "last": true,
  "totalElements": 2,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "size": 20,
  "number": 0,
  "first": true,
  "sort": null,
  "numberOfElements": 2
}
```

I want to convert long to date, so I create 1 object to binding data:

```
export class myApp {
    id: number;
    classId: string;
    trainingDate: string;
    examDate: string;

}
```

on my ts:

```
listData = new Array();

  app_unit:myApp= new myApp();
  listApp:any[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllTrainingClass();

  }
 async getAllTrainingClass(): Promise<void>{
     await this.traningClassService.getdata().then(data =>this.listApp = data);

     for(let ls of this.listApp){


        this.app_unit.classId= ls.classId;
        this.app_unit.examDate=this.convertTimestampToDate(ls.examDate);
        this.app_unit.trainingDate=this.convertTimestampToDate(ls.startDate) +'-'+this.convertTimestampToDate(ls.endDate) ;

       this.listData.push(this.app_unit);


     }
```

the console log of has 2 item,  but it is the latest item, like as:

{0:myApp
id:2
classId:null
examDate:"05/01/2018"
trainingDate:"05/11/2017-31/12/2017"
},
{1:myApp
id:2
classId:null
examDate:"05/01/2018"
trainingDate:"05/11/2017-31/12/2017"}

please advice me.

Comment: I think the problem is because this.app_unit. is pointing to the same memory location, ie you are inserting the same object into the array, all pointing to the same memory location.

Comment: put, var app_unit:myApp= new myApp(); inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because "this.app_unit" is pointing to the same memory location, you are inserting the same object into the array, all pointing to the same memory location.

Put,

```
  var app_unit:myApp= new myApp();
```

inside the for loop.
Thus, a new instance of the object is created with each loop.

Comment: try to create it inside  the loop. but the error is displayed:Cannot assign to 'myApp' because it is not a variable.

Comment: Np, I forgot the declaration